# jquery image preload and error detection

Tags: jquery, image-preloader

Long time listener, first time caller...

I've got a page where I'm trying to preload an array of images and replace any missing ones before they are shown. I'm currently using a standard image loader which works fine but doesn't help with broken links

**Preload function**

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
preload([image.jpg]);
```

How do I use jQuery to preload the set of images and replace broken links with a static link, all before they are used on the page? The idea is to prevent the missing image '?' ever appearing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `error()` to detect when an image is not loaded correctly.

Try

```
$('<img/>').error(function() {$(this).attr("src","your_static_link_here");});
```

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't appear to fire when there is a missing image and therefore no replacement happens. `$('<img/>')[0].src = this;
   $('<img/>').error(function() {
    console.log('error loading');
    $(this).attr("src","http://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png");    
   });`

Comment: @maccaj22 Can you provide a fiddle?